# How to group in CQLinq?

Tags: c#, ndepend, cqlinq

I have an autogenerated interface and implementation which define 3000+ methods and for each one the respective asynchronous signature. All in all 6,000+ methods.

I would like to figure out which ones are NOT used. Here is the CQLinq I have so far:

```cs
// Unused methods in the interface
let notUsed1 = new HashSet<IMethod>( 
from t in JustMyCode.Types 
where t.Name == "IDataProcessor"
from m in t.Methods 
where !m.HasAttribute("xyz.CoreService.CoreServiceOperationAttribute") &&  !m.MethodsCallingMe.Any()
select m)
// Unused methods in the concrete implementation of the interface
let notUsed2 =
from t in JustMyCode.Types 
where t.Name == "DataProcessor"
from m in t.Methods 
where m.HasAttribute("System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute") && !m.MethodsCallingMe.Any()
// Obtain the methods in the intersection
select m
from m in notUsed2 where notUsed1.Contains(m.OverriddensBase.Single())
let baseName = m.SimpleName.Replace("Async", "")
group m by baseName into g
select new { g }
```

Alas, this does not work. The error message is:

```
Ln 18  Col 8  Type {IGrouping`2<String,IMethod>} not accepted to type first result argument.
Only IMethod, IField, IType, INamespace, IAssembly, IMember, ICodeElement, ICodeElementParent, ICodeContainer, IIssue and IRule are accepted to type first result argument.
```

Looks like `group` is out of the question. My idea is to group the methods by the base name (which is the same for synchronous and asynchronous signatures) and select those entries which have 2 items. But it looks like my plan would not work because grouping is not supported.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it by changing the grouping key to be an `IMethod` object:

```cs
// Collect the sync methods
let syncMethods = (
from t in JustMyCode.Types 
where t.Name == "IDataProcessor"
from m in t.Methods 
where !m.HasAttribute("xyz.CoreService.CoreServiceOperationAttribute") && !m.IsAsync
select m).ToDictionary(m => m.SimpleName)
// Unused methods in the interface
let notUsed1 = new HashSet<IMethod>( 
from t in JustMyCode.Types 
where t.Name == "IDataProcessor"
from m in t.Methods 
where !m.HasAttribute("xyz.CoreService.CoreServiceOperationAttribute") && !m.MethodsCallingMe.Any()
select m)
// Unused methods in the concrete implementation of the interface
let notUsed2 =
from t in JustMyCode.Types 
where t.Name == "DataProcessor"
from m in t.Methods 
where m.HasAttribute("System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute") && !m.MethodsCallingMe.Any()
// Select methods in the intersection
select m
from m in notUsed2 where notUsed1.Contains(m.OverriddensBase.Single())
let syncMethod = syncMethods[m.SimpleName.Replace("Async", "")]
group m by syncMethod into g     // group by the respective sync method
where g.Count() == 2     // return if both sync and async signatures are not used
select new { g.Key }
```

I wonder how this can be simplified.

Comment: Maybe you could first use a let clause to match methods of IDataProcessor and then reuse this set in the 2x next let clauses, smthing like   let interfaceMethods = JustMyCode.Type.WithName("IDataProcessor").ChildMethods()